# Why don't match the path?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, filepath, java-io

Hy

I have a problem, I try to save a file to custom directory, but doesn't work.

First of all I choosen the downloads directory, but the copy doesn't work.

If I add a constans directory folder, the downloads, the copy is working.

The problem is that, the two directory path doesn't exists.

If i add a constans path, for example:

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`
The path is : `/storage/emulated/0/Download`

But if i add a custom path from intent, and i choose the downloads directory, tha path is : `com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads`

My function to copy file:

```
database.close();
        File sourceDb = context.getDatabasePath("app_database");
        File destinationDb = new File(filePath + "/app_database");
        File file=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(sourceDb, destinationDb);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error";
        }
```

And my Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), 100);


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==100){
            informationSnackbar(data.getData().toString());
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not return a `File`. It returns a `Uri` pointing to a `DocumentsProvider`.

To write to the document identified by the `Uri`, use `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` to which you can copy the database.